# Getting distance traveled with lat and lon

Tags: android, gps

I'm creating an `ArrayList` of Lat/Lon coords and then want to take all of them and find the total distance traveled. But my current code keeps returning 0. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
public float getDistanceTraveled() {
    float[] dist = new float[1];
    float totalDist = 0;

        for(int i = 0; locs.size()-2 >= i; i++) {
            double lat1 = locs.get(i).getLatitude();
            double lon1 = locs.get(i+1).getLongitude();
            double lat2 = locs.get(i).getLatitude();
            double lon2 = locs.get(i+1).getLongitude();

            Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, dist);
            totalDist += dist[0];
            Log.d("", "totaldist " + String.valueOf(totalDist));

        }
        return totalDist;       
}
```

Comment: Log `lat1`, `lon1`, `lat2`, and `lon2` and see if their values look right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a case of a small type-o, shouldn't it be this instead:

```
double lat1 = locs.get(i).getLatitude();
double lon1 = locs.get(i).getLongitude();
double lat2 = locs.get(i+1).getLatitude();
double lon2 = locs.get(i+1).getLongitude();
```

edit: looks like Morrison beat me to it

Answer (score 2):

So your getting the distance between the same point or is that lat from one point and long from another?

```
        double lat1 = locs.get(i).getLatitude();
        double lon1 = locs.get(i+1).getLongitude();
        double lat2 = locs.get(i).getLatitude();
        double lon2 = locs.get(i+1).getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that this will be as the crow flies, but if I go from one waypoint, around a turn and go down another street, it may look like I went 100m when I went 2 miles.

So, unless you are taking a sufficient number of points to handle the issue where roads curve and people go onto different roads, your number will be very different than if you use the navigator to see the distance.

As other have mentioned your typo I won't go into the detail of why distance was zero, but you may want to think your approach.

Now, if the user is walking, or perhaps biking, your approach may be fine, but for driving you may want to test a great deal and see if you are happy with the discrepancy.

Comment: i realize this is as the crow flies. which is fine for me. (at least for now) the typo was the problem.